# trying to produce a cross diagram with quadratic inputs

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-arrows

I produce something like below but have not able all I have is the nodes but it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
   vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=2em},
   edge/.style = {->,-Latex},
   ]
   % Vertices
   \node[vertex] (c) at (0,0) {6};
   \node[vertex] (a) at (-2,-2) {};
   \node[vertex] (b) at (2,-2) {};
   \node[vertex] (d) at (0,-3) {6};
   \node[vertex] (e) at (-1,-5) {?};
   \node[vertex] (f) at (1,-5 {?};
   \node[vertex] (g) at (-2,-7) {};
   \node[vertex] (h) at (0,-7) {5};
   \node[vertex] (i) at (2,-7) {};
   \node[vertex] (bx) at (0,-9) {5};
   % Edges
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (a) -- (c) node[midway,left] {$\times$}  ;
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (b) -- (c) node[midway,right] {$\times$} ;
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (g) -- (bx) node[midway,left] {$\times$}  ;
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (I) -- (bx) node[midway,right] {$\times$} ;
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (a)t to  node[left] {} (i);

  \end{document}
```

[image: What I like, rotated]

If you know hw to just write the equation to make this work that would be amazing but equally as good if I could just hand type the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to correct your diagram, which wasn't that bad after all:

- corrected some typos (see `% <<<` )
- added missing information
- added `\end{tikzpicture}` (i.e. close the environment)
- corrected operators
- added missing line
- adjusted y-coordinates a little

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
   vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=2em},
   edge/.style = {->,-Latex},
   ]
   % Vertices
   \node[vertex] (c) at (0,0) {6};
   \node[vertex] (a) at (-2,-2) {3};% <<< missing content
   \node[vertex] (b) at (2,-2) {2};% <<< missing content
   \node[vertex] (d) at (0,-3) {6};
   \node[vertex] (e) at (-1,-4.5) {?};% adjusted y-coordinate
   \node[vertex] (f) at ( 1,-4.5) {?};% <<< missing ), adjusted y-coordinate
   \node[vertex] (g) at (-2,-7) {2};% <<< missing content
   \node[vertex] (h) at (0,-7) {5};
   \node[vertex] (i) at (2,-7) {3};% <<< missing content
   \node[vertex] (bx) at (0,-9) {5};
   % Edges
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (a) -- (c) node[midway,left] {$\times$}  ;
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (b) -- (c) node[midway,right] {$\times$} ;
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (b) -- (g) node[midway,right] {} ;% missing line
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (g) -- (bx) node[midway,left] {$+$}  ;% wrong operator
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (i) -- (bx) node[midway,right] {$+$} ;% typo I, wrong operator
   \draw[edge, ultra thick] (a) to  node[left] {} (i);% <<< typo excessive t
 \end{tikzpicture}% <<< missing

\end{document}
```